# HTML5 Video progress slider

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar, html5-video

So I'm trying to create a progress slider for an HTML5 video. So I have the video on the page and when you hit play (whether via a button or the video itself) the video starts and updates a progress bar.  I also wanted to place an image inside the progress bar and make the progress bar clickable to skip through the video.  Any ideas how to do this with Javascript.  I can't seem to find any help online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a demo here :
http://people.mozilla.org/~cpearce/buffered-demo.html

I have made this player, although the code is not made to be easy for others to understand but it seems to be what you are looking for with canvas clickable progress bar where you can draw your image :
http://netkoder.dk/netkoder/video_chernobyl.php

Standalone version : http://netkoder.dk/netkoder/eksempler/eksempel0109.html

Comment: Wow thanks! Do you happen to have a raw copy of the code for download?

Comment: No i havent have a easy to understand standalone example yet. I could try and make a standalone example.

Comment: Here is a standalone version http://netkoder.dk/netkoder/eksempler/eksempel0109.html

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas of how to draw a .png image to the canvas?

Comment: Use context.drawImage() but you have to preload the image first otherwise it wont show up all the time : http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/

Comment: Wow thank you so much, you are a life saver!  Will this work on mobile devices using PhoneGap?

Comment: Dont know i dont use phonegap.